# htaccess - Remove multiple slashes after domain with encoded accented characters

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I can remove multiple slashes anywhere in URL using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work for multiple slashes after the domain

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

- from: [remove multiple trailing slashes mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846225/remove-multiple-trailing-slashes-mod-rewrite)

and

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ (.*)//([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ %2/%3 [R=301,L]
```

- from: [Remove trailing slash after domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705403/remove-trailing-slash-after-domain)

both produce the expected rewirting when going from

```
domain.com/////hello
```

to

```
domain.com/hello
```

but from

```
 domain.com/////héllo
```

the result is encoded

```
domain.com/h%25c%25allo
```

How to prevent accented characters to get encoded when removing multiple slashes after domain ?

**EDIT: pear to anubhava's answer**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

The accented character is protected and trimed with succes with more than to repeated slashes

```
domain.com////////héllo
```

but not with only 2

```
domain.com//héllo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)/+(/[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

This will do these redirections:

1. `/////help => /help`
2. `/////héllo/////abc/////123 => /héllo/abc/123`

Comment: the accented character is protected but the result is domain.com//héllo

Comment: I have updated the question according to your answer. would it be possible to add a [OR] condition to deal with the double slash?

Comment: This will also work for `domain.com/////héllo/////abc/////123` redirecting that to `domain.com/héllo/abc/123`

Comment: in fact not for me... testing... true!! I have forgotten the other cleanning rules after thisone. thanks anubhava it is officially the best answer from now

Answer (score 0):

anubhava's answer is the shortest but alternatively this one is also working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```