# match multiple slashes in url, but not in protocol

Tags: regex, .htaccess

i try to catch multiple slashes at the ende or inside of url, but not those slashes (which could be two or more), which are placed after protocol (http://, https://, ftp:// file:///)

i tried many findings in similar SO-threads, like `^(.*)//+(.*)$` or `[^:](\/{2,})`, or `^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$` in http://www.regexr.com/, https://regex101.com and http://www.regextester.com/. But nothing worked clear for me.

Its pretty weird, that i can't find a working example - this goal isn't such rar. Could somebody share a working regex?

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: @anubhava: no:( tested with the three sites i cited above, doesn't work. Tried to escape slahes - same, doesn't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its for apache/htaccess

Comment: Here, [`(?:https?|ftps?|file)://(*SKIP)(*F)|//`](https://regex101.com/r/lN7mB8/1) - not sure it will work in htaccess, anubhava will help you better with this

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no:( error: https://regex101.com/r/nF5mI1/1

Comment: @ChillyBang: You chose a wrong regex delimiter - it works. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/nF5mI1/2), but I doubt it will work in htaccess, I am out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with this delimiter it matches only two slashes. And: how should such delimiters be added to `RewriteCond`?

Comment: I suggested that before you said you need it for htaccess. I have no clue, sorry.

Comment: @anubhava i try to redirect everything with more then one slash to canonical url notation

Comment: `RewriteCond` doesn't match against `http://` or `ftp://` and absolutely no way against `file:///`

Comment: @anubhava sure, it can't, but regex could catch the combination of `:/`, which will not happen inside or at the end of urls. Thats the idea behind: to catch all multiple slashes, where doesn't stays a `:` before

Comment: No actually `RewriteCond` compares only part after `http://` in `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` OR `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rule that you can use in your site root .htaccess to strip out multiple slashes anywhere from input URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`.

Pattern inside `RewriteRule` automatically converts multiple slashes into single one.

Comment: does it work only on the url's end? your rule for multiple slashes in the middle of url has other look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21513277/1992004